# Discord.js - Send file to folder on PC

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am giving one of my bots a youtube download command because I both am tired of using the sketchy ones on the internet and also ran out of things to code. So far my code gets the video in question and returns the file in the chat, and it works great, except for the fact that 90% of the videos are too big to be sent. So what I want to do is to save the file to `D:\bot_yt_vids\` or something but I cannot figure out how to do this (I have searched everywhere and nothing works for some reason)
My current code is this:

```
var splitMessage = message.content.split(' ');
if (splitMessage[0] === "!ytdl") {
        try {
            const vid = ytdl(splitMessage[1], { filter: format => format.container === 'mp4' })
            message.channel.send({ files: [{ attachment: vid, name: "video  .mp4" }] })
        } catch (e) { message.channel.send("An error occured"); console.log(e)}

        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ytdl()` returns a readable file stream, so I suggest looking creating a new `writableStream` in node.js and using the `.pipe()` method of a readable stream to pass it to the writable stream to write to the file. I'm not familiar with filestreams, but I think that should be all you need.

[readableStream#pipe](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)

[Great article on filestreams](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93/)